# How to handle exception in Guzzle Async request?

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle

I have problem when i try download many images using Guzzle. Some of them probably invalid, so when i made AsyncRequest i cant handle exception of every images.

I tried to make validation method, which must work with downloaded files, but it doesnt work on-time.

```php
$requests = function () use ($client, $imagesMetaData) {
            foreach ($imagesMetaData as $index => $image) {
                yield $index => function () use ($client, $image) {
                    try {
                        $resource = fopen($image['savePath'], 'w+b');
                        if (!$resource) {
                            // do smth
                        }

                        $opts = ['sink' => $resource];
                        $result = $client->requestAsync('GET', $image['downloadUri'], $opts);

                        return ($result);

                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $image['writeLog'](
                            // do smth
                        );

                        return new Response(404);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

Pool::batch($client, $requests(), [
                'concurrency' => 5,
                'fulfilled'   => function (Response $response, $index) use ($me, $imagesMetaData, &$fulfilled, &$rejected) {
                    $image = $imagesMetaData[$index];

                    foreach ($imagesMetaData as $image) {
                        if ($me->validateDownloadedImage($image)) {
                            $fulfilled[] = $image;
                        } else {
                            $rejected[] = $image;
                        }
                    }
                },
                'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use ($me, $imagesMetaData, &$rejected) {

                    $image = $imagesMetaData[$index];

                    $me->rejectImage($image, $reason);
                    $rejected[] = $image;
                }
            ]);

            return [$fulfilled, $rejected];
```

If files images are fine - everything work as expected, but if one of them failed - i have next error

Catalog import exception of type RuntimeException thrown in file /var/www/my.site/localhost/core/libraries/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php at line 250. Unable to write to stream.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJnHn.png

If someone know this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with opening stream:

```php
$stream   = stream_for($resource);
```

and pass this stream to 'sink'
:

```php
'sink' => $stream
```

final code looks like this:

```php
$requests = function () use ($client, $imagesMetaData) {
            foreach ($imagesMetaData as $index => $image) {
                yield $index => function () use ($client, $image) {
                    try {
                        $resource = fopen($image['savePath'], 'w+b');
                        $stream   = stream_for($resource);

                        if (!$resource) {
                            // do smth
                        }

                        $opts = ['sink' => $stream];
                        $result = $client->requestAsync('GET', $image['downloadUri'], $opts);

                        return ($result);

                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $image['writeLog'](
                            // do smth
                        );

                        return new Response(404);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

Pool::batch($client, $requests(), [
                'concurrency' => 5,
                'fulfilled'   => function (Response $response, $index) use ($me, $imagesMetaData, &$fulfilled, &$rejected) {
                    $image = $imagesMetaData[$index];

                    foreach ($imagesMetaData as $image) {
                        if ($me->validateDownloadedImage($image)) {
                            $fulfilled[] = $image;
                        } else {
                            $rejected[] = $image;
                        }
                    }
                },
                'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use ($me, $imagesMetaData, &$rejected) {

                    $image = $imagesMetaData[$index];

                    $me->rejectImage($image, $reason);
                    $rejected[] = $image;
                }
            ]);

            return [$fulfilled, $rejected];
```